# Evaluate $\sum\limits_{k=3}^{k=7} {(k+1)\choose (7-k)}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

I came across this problem in which we had to evaluate $$\sum\limits_{k=3}^{k=7} {(k+1)\choose (7-k)}$$
All I could think of was to put in the values of *k* and get $${4\choose4}+{5\choose3}+{6\choose2}+{7\choose1}+{8\choose0} = 34$$
Is there a more efficient way (possibly using binomial concept) to solve this sum?

Comment: There is no better way.

Comment: Fibonnacci may help you

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio Could you elaborate pls?

Comment: This is $\sum\limits_{k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor}^{k=n} {k+1\choose n-k}$ when $n=7$.  Try it for other values of $n$ and you may understand @IsaacYIUMathStudio's comment

Comment: So does it mean that every sum of this form that @henry has given in his comment can be evaluated using Fibonacci?

Comment: I would simply use a computer, just as we often use computers for other large sums.